# MIPS array declaration with size the User dictates

Tags: arrays, mips, declaration

I have to write a program that takes 3 user-inputs:

1. The starting value (A)
2. The value that shall be added (B)
3. The amount of times the addition shall be done (C)

In the end I put out all sums like this:
    A, A+B, A+B+B, ...

My problem at the time is, that i want to save all of these sums in an Array to put them out later. Normally you would allocate space for said Array like this:

```
    data:
         Array: .space 400
```

Because I can't do this later in the code where i got my C value, I have to find another way to declare the Array.

My Question now is: How do I declare my Array later in my code with the length C?

Comment: You haven't mentioned your target environment. If you're running this in a simulator like SPIM or MARS, you'd allocate memory using system call 9 (`sbrk`). If you're running this on a MIPS-based Linux system where you have access to libc you can simply call `malloc`.

Comment: I run the program in MARS. So do i just have to use syscall 9 with C in $v0? And how do i read/write in that Array?

Comment: The size is specified in bytes, so if you need `C` words you should allocate `C*4` bytes. You access the memory through the address returned in `$v0`.

Comment: So i would store something in the Array by writing
        sw $someregisterWhereIGetTheWordFrom, 0($v0) ?

Comment: Yeah, it's no different from how you would do things after an `la $v0,Array`.

Comment: Ok i will try that out now. Thank you very much Michael :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the help of Micheal I know now that I can just write the size of the storage to $v0 and then use the syscall 9 to allocate that space.
To write to it I can just use the sw-Command like I would normally use it.